# Bad way of displaying warnings/errors in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have strange issue with Android Studio build warnings and errors. I have Android Studio Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 2 , in project I'm using latest KSP version.

I don't know when exactly issue started, by I remember that always I had list of file names/classes and now there is full path and to open issue I have to click it and on right panel select hyperlink to file.

[image: issue ilustration]

Does anyone know how to bring "normal" behaviour of this window?